# Select creatives of type TemplateCreatives with DoubleClick DFP

Tags: python, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

How can I query for creatives of Type *TemplateCreative* with the DoubleClick DFP API

I am able to query for creatives with the DFP API by using PQL and the [Python Google Ads API Library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib).

Like this:

```
    from googleads import dfp
    client = dfp.DfpClient.LoadFromStorage('./googleads.yaml')
    creative_service = client.GetService('CreativeService', version='v201502')
    creative_query = '' 
    creative_statement = dfp.FilterStatement(creative_query, creative_values)
    while True: 
        response = creative_service.getCreativesByStatement(
                       creative_statement.ToStatement())
        if 'results' in response:
                #do your thing
        creative_statement.offset += dfp.SUGGESTED_PAGE_LIMIT
```

This  will return all creatives. It works as advertised! In my case a combination of `ImageCreative`, `CustomCreative` and `TemplateCreative`

When I use the query to select only ImageCreatives. It also works!

Like this:

```
    from googleads import dfp
    client = dfp.DfpClient.LoadFromStorage('./googleads.yaml')
    creative_service = client.GetService('CreativeService', version='v201502')
    creative_values = [{ 'key': 'creativeType', 'value'::{ 
                           'xsi_type': 'TextValue', 
                           'value': 'ImageCreative' 
                         }     
                        }]
    creative_query = 'WHERE creativeType = :creativeType'
    creative_statement = dfp.FilterStatement(creative_query, creative_values)
      while True: 
        response = creative_service.getCreativesByStatement(
               creative_statement.ToStatement())
        if 'results' in response:
                #do your thing
        creative_statement.offset += dfp.SUGGESTED_PAGE_LIMIT
```

If I search for CustomCreative it also works.  However I don't seem to be able to query for TemplateCreative

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: It seems that the DFP API does not support this: [Getting creatives by type TemplateCreative](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api/TemplateCreative/google-doubleclick-for-publishers-api/8fIMmQaJtjE/RSbWRm9VjXsJ)

The solution I have adopted is getting all *Creatives* and parse them. Which sucks. Like this:

```
   for creative in response['results']: 
       if "TemplateCreative" in str(creative.__class__):
```